# Chrome Extension: Hide and show the browser action icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

Is it possible to show and hide the browser action icon from the options page?

I know how to do it with the page actions using the show and hide methods, but I don't see any similarities in browser actions.

Answer (score 12):

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction:

> If you want to create an icon that isn't always visible, use a page action instead of a browser action.

In other words: no, this isn't possible. Browser actions are permanent by design.

Comment: Wladimir, I've read this page a lot of times, and I hadn't seen this sentence, and it's in the first paragraphs! Thanks!

Comment: @Oscardr: Feel free to accept the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ;)

Comment: That's why i hate links, broken!

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere: Wrong redirect on Google's servers, nothing that a quick Google search cannot fix. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, Page icons are always shown too... just grayed out when disabled.

Comment: @Pacerier: They are now, this answer is from 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Google defined Browser Action as static buttons, and Page Action as dynamic ones.
Google is very careful with Chrome's interface, and don't want people use buttons in a different way they are "supposed" to do.

They do so because they think users have tu put an effort to learn to use Chrome, and Google want to present a consistent, coherent and minimalist user interface.

You don't have much freedom with regard to Chrome user interface.